# how innerHTML property works on sublime text 3

Tags: innerhtml

var a;

document.querySelector(".header").innerHTML="

## WOW

";

a = document.querySelector(".header").innerHTML;

console.log(a);

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is a `DOM API`  property which is used to get or set the `HTML` markup inside an element. `Sublime 3` is just a text editor.

Your code should be like this:

```js
var a;

const b = document.querySelector(".header")

b.innerHTML = 'WOW'

a = document.querySelector(".header").innerHTML;

console.log(a);
```

```html
<div class='header'></div>
```